# Is there any way to inspect DB data when running FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rspec, factory-bot, guard

**Setup:** Hi, I have Rails 3.2, Guard, RSpec and FactoryGirl. Pretty common.

**The Problem:** The user I created as admin doesn't behave as expected. Also, when the tests are finished, the database is already empty, so I can't understand what's happening.

**Desired:** I'd like to "debug", or - in other words - to have some breakpoint and inspect my_test database.

**- OR -** At least I'd like to DB to be cleaned in the beginning of tests, not at the end.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the debugger gem and you'll be able to drop into the debugger by calling `debugger`

Tests are wrapped in a transaction and on most (all?) databases this means that other connections (for example the one opened by whatever database browsing tool you use) can't see the changes made by your test. You can change this on mysql with

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
```

Other databases may vary

Comment: Hi Frederick, I ran this SET on DB, now I run "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec guard -d" and it looks like it stops, but when inspecting anything - variables or DB - they are empty. Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like I have to run "set transaction isolation level read uncommitted" each time I need to inspect. Then in works!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for to see what my rspec tests were up to in my database. I just use this SET in my SQL query, above my select * and I can see everything I need to. Thank you so much for this.